# Extract information from json file on websites just by javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How to extract information from JSON file on websites just by JavaScript. 
I can use a meta tag but the information is not enough. So I have to use JSON. That is JSON data embedded on a webpage:

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "https://www.schema.org",
"@type": "Product",
"name": "TF4081L02M",
"image": [
{
"url": "https://polekala.com/images/53/54/15299/main_tumb.jpg",
}
],
"description": "",
"sku": "15299",
"aggregateRating": {
"@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": 5,
"reviewCount": 40,
"bestRating": 5,
"worstRating": 0
},
},
"review": {
"@type": "Review",
"author": "",
"datePublished": "2019-12-14T00:11:02.047",
"description": ".",
"name": "Best",
"reviewRating": {
"@type": "Rating",
"bestRating": 5,
"ratingValue": 5,
"worstRating": 0
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you exactly need?

Comment: umm....Tried to find the question...where is it?

Comment: the information like description i want show this information in console

Comment: i can use metetag i read it `function extractProductData () {
        var productInfo = {};
        var sku = document.querySelector('input[name="product"]');
        if (!sku) {
            return false;
        }     `

Comment: `JSON file on the website`? website only have HTML content to grep as far as i know :)

Comment: It's really not clear what the problem is here. Fetching the HTML? (Do you even need to fetch the HTML or is the JS running in the same page?). Extracting the JSON from the DOM? Parsing the JSON? Getting data out of the parsed object? What do metatags have to do with this? Or input elements?

Comment: Extracting the JSON from the DOM ******** i need this

Comment: i want to chose last script what can i do??

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment that the specific thing you needed help with was:

> Extracting the JSON from the DOM

So, you need to find the script element:

```
const script = document.querySelector('script');
```

You might need to be more specific if there are multiple script elements and that one isn't the first, so perhaps:

```
const script = document.querySelector('script[type="application/ld+json"]');
```

If that isn't enough, then you'll need to adjust it based on the context the element appears in.

Then you need to get the JSON content of the element:

```
const json = script.textContent;
```

You can then parse that JSON string to get a regular JavaScript object.

Comment: i use this code but the resualt is undifine   `var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script["application/ld+json"]');
var json = script.textContent;
console.log(json);`

Comment: The result of *that* isn't `undefined`, it throws an exception. I made a typo in an earlier revision of the question. The current code works fine: https://jsbin.com/bacelakina/edit?html,js,console